# Am I correct with this change of variable?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, definite-integrals, proof-verification

I have been solving a problem from a paper I read related to poisson point processes and for some reason I am not reaching the same result the paper has.

The problem is re-expressing an expression by change of variable. 
The expression is $$\int_{\gamma_2}^{+\infty} \big[1 - \frac{1}{1+sx^{-1}}\big]\lambda(x)\ dx $$
$$\lambda(x)= x^{\frac{2}{\alpha}-1}$$
so the authors claim with a simple change of variable $$x=st^\alpha$$ I should be able to rewrite it as 
$$ F(\gamma_2 s^{-1})^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\alpha \ s^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}$$ where the function F is defined as $$F(x)=\int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{r}{r^{\alpha}+1}dr$$

However with my derivation I seem to obtain $$\int_{(\gamma_2 s^{-1})^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+t^{-\alpha}}\alpha \ s^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}dt$$

Who is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a factor of $t$ missing. it comes from 
$$
(st^{\alpha})^{\frac2{\alpha}-1}d(st^{\alpha})
$$

Comment: $$\int_{\gamma_2}^{+\infty} \big[\frac{t^{-\alpha}}{1+t^{-\alpha}}\big]\big(st^{\alpha})^{\frac2{\alpha}-1}d(st^{\alpha})$$